# Integrating Google Maps api with React js (draggable maker not returning coordinates)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We're currently trying to integrate the google maps javascript api with a form.

We've managed to get the map working so when the user adds their address a query search is performed, however, we also want the user to be able to drag the marker to the actual location if the address is represented differently on the map.

Here's the code so far:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const GoogleMap = ({ placeName, address, town, postcode, setLocation }) => {
  const googleMapRef = useRef();
  let googleMap;

  const createGoogleMap = coordinates => {
    googleMap = new window.google.maps.Map(googleMapRef.current, {
      zoom: 16,
      center: {
        lat: coordinates.lat(),
        lng: coordinates.lng(),
      },
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    });
  };

  let marker;

  const getLatLng = () => {
    let lat;
    let lng;
    let placeId;
    new window.google.maps.Geocoder().geocode(
      { address: `${placeName}, ${address}, ${town}, ${postcode}, region:'uk'` },
      (results, status) => {
        if (status === window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          placeId = results[0].place_id;
          createGoogleMap(results[0].geometry.location);
          lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          setLocation({ latitude: lat, longitude: lng });
          marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat, lng },
            map: googleMap,
            animation: window.google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: `${placeName}`,
            draggable: true,
          });
          marker.addListener("dragend");
          console.log(marker);
        } else {
          console.error(`Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ${status}`);
        }
      },
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const googleMapScript = document.createElement("script");
    googleMapScript.src = apiKey;
    googleMapScript.async = true;
    window.document.body.appendChild(googleMapScript);
    googleMapScript.addEventListener("load", () => {
      getLatLng();
    });
  }, [placeName, postcode, marker]);

  return <div id="google-map" ref={googleMapRef} style={{ width: "100%", height: "60vh" }} />;
};

GoogleMap.defaultProps = {
  placeName: undefined,
  address: undefined,
  town: undefined,
  postcode: undefined,
};

GoogleMap.propTypes = {
  placeName: PropTypes.string,
  address: PropTypes.string,
  town: PropTypes.string,
  postcode: PropTypes.string,
  setLocation: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default GoogleMap;
```

Any help or advice on this at this point would be great.

Comment: Seems like you already do (by `draggable: true`). So what's the issue now?

Comment: That prop makes the marker draggable but it does not return the latitude and longitude on drop.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to fix it. Here's the solution:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { error } from "../../../../Utils/toast";

const GoogleMap = ({ placeName, address, town, postcode, setLocation }) => {
  const googleMapRef = useRef();
  let googleMap;

  const createGoogleMap = coordinates => {
    googleMap = new window.google.maps.Map(googleMapRef.current, {
      zoom: 16,
      center: {
        lat: coordinates.lat(),
        lng: coordinates.lng(),
      },
      disableDefaultUI: true,
    });
  };

  let marker;

  function markerCoords(markerobject) {
    window.google.maps.event.addListener(markerobject, "dragend", evt => {
      setLocation({ latitude: evt.latLng.lat(), longitude: evt.latLng.lng() });
    });
  }

  const getLatLng = () => {
    let lat;
    let lng;
    new window.google.maps.Geocoder().geocode(
      { address: `${placeName}, ${address}, ${town}, ${postcode}, region:'uk'` },
      (results, status) => {
        if (status === window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          createGoogleMap(results[0].geometry.location);
          lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          setLocation({ latitude: lat, longitude: lng });
          marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat, lng },
            map: googleMap,
            animation: window.google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: `${placeName}`,
            draggable: true,
          });
          markerCoords(marker);
        } else {
          error(`Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ${status}`);
        }
      },
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const googleMapScript = document.createElement("script");
    googleMapScript.src = apiKey;
    googleMapScript.async = true;
    window.document.body.appendChild(googleMapScript);
    googleMapScript.addEventListener("load", () => {
      getLatLng();
    });
  }, [placeName, postcode, marker]);

  return <div id="google-map" ref={googleMapRef} style={{ width: "100%", height: "60vh" }} />;
};

GoogleMap.defaultProps = {
  placeName: undefined,
  address: undefined,
  town: undefined,
  postcode: undefined,
};

GoogleMap.propTypes = {
  placeName: PropTypes.string,
  address: PropTypes.string,
  town: PropTypes.string,
  postcode: PropTypes.string,
  setLocation: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default GoogleMap;
```